# Laravel 5.5 - login explained?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

My problem, or rather question is regarding the actual Login function of the builtin Authenthication feature by Laravel (v5.5).

I simply do not understand where the magic happens regarding logging the user into the system.

Here the login method within the **LoginController**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }


        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

and here the attemptedLogin method butthis one still does not give me any closure.

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Can ANYONE explain to me where exactly in laravel a user gets logged in into the application? i cant read it out of the documentation either.
Either i'm too blind or stupid but i really do not see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well you're smart enough to have started down the right path. continue down the rabbit hole, the goods are inside `guard()->attempt()`

Comment: @castis has the right idea. [Here's more to help you out](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php). As a side note, OP has the right to be pissed. It's really hard to follow the code. Magic methods everywhere.

Comment: Also take a look on the trait AuthenticatesUsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your hunch is correct. The actual login (match credentials and if successful, log user in) happens in the `attemptLogin` method. It's simply the same as an `Auth::attempt` call as explained in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users)

To understand the code completely, just read the code with the comments. I've pulled in the code below from the `AuthenticatesUsers` and `ThrottlesLogins` traits. **The comments are pretty self explanatory**:

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }
    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
    }
    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
/**
 * Validate the user login request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
} 
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
}
/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 * @throws ValidationException
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
    ]);
}
/**
 * Determine if the user has too many failed login attempts.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
    return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
        $this->throttleKey($request), $this->maxAttempts(), $this->decayMinutes()
    );
}
/**
 * Increment the login attempts for the user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function incrementLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
    $this->limiter()->hit(
        $this->throttleKey($request), $this->decayMinutes()
    );
}
/**
 * Redirect the user after determining they are locked out.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
{
    $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(
        $this->throttleKey($request)
    );
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        $this->username() => [Lang::get('auth.throttle', ['seconds' => $seconds])],
    ])->status(423);
}
/**
 * Clear the login locks for the given user credentials.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function clearLoginAttempts(Request $request)
{
    $this->limiter()->clear($this->throttleKey($request));
}
/**
 * Fire an event when a lockout occurs.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function fireLockoutEvent(Request $request)
{
    event(new Lockout($request));
}
/**
 * Get the throttle key for the given request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return string
 */
protected function throttleKey(Request $request)
{
    return Str::lower($request->input($this->username())).'|'.$request->ip();
}
/**
 * Get the rate limiter instance.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter
 */
protected function limiter()
{
    return app(RateLimiter::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

in `/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`

this is where the user finally gets logged in to the session.

You could also just add `Auth::loginUsingId($userId)` with the right user id to login a user. (Thats not safe)

Answer (score 0):

I have spent the last few days trying to find the answer to almost the same question, so maybe I will be able to somehow clarify it a bit :)

How the user is authenticated depends on which guard you're using for a given model.

Just as you already know, the attemptLogin method is called on the result of the guard() method:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

If you use the default 'session' guard, this method returns an instance of `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php` class.

This class, in turn, defines `attempt` method, which calls the `login` method if the user credentials are valid. This seems to be the final place, where the user is actually authenticated.